# Phase 10 Skip card play rules

Tags: phase-10

When a skip card is played does the player get to draw and lay down again, or is it the discard itself?

Answer (score 1):

Discarding the Skip card is playing it. Once the player has selected who will miss the next turn, their own turn is now over.

A player never draws twice in one turn, and can only discard one card at most (though they can lay down and hit as many cards as legitimately possible).